# Is it possible to run vbs file in php

Tags: php

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$obj = $WshShell->Run("Test.vbs");
```

I try run this command on php, but it does not work.

Comment: VB.NET has nothing to do with VBScript.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not very helpful.  Any error message?  You could use `new COM("WScript.Shell") or die("Couldn't create the COM Component");` to check if the module is loaded.  Also make sure the vbs file is accessible.